# Replacing all occurrences of a pattern in a string

Tags: r, character

Used to run R with numbers and matrix, when it comes to play with strings and characters I am lost. I want to analyze some data where the time is read into R as follow:

```
>my.time.char[1]
[1] "\"2011-10-05 15:55:00\""
```

I want to end up with a string containing only:

```
"2011-10-05 15:55:00"
```

Using the function sub() (that i barely understand...), I got the following result:

```
> sub("(\")","",my.time.char[1])
[1] "2011-10-05 15:55:00\""
```

This is closer to the format i am looking for, but I still need to get rid of the two last characters (`\"`).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The second line from `?sub` explains:

> sub and gsub perform replacement of the first and all matches respectively.

which should tell you to use `gsub` instead.